# Set Theory problem count of subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A set contains 2n+1 elements. Then, what is the number of subsets of the set which contain at most n elements ?

(A) $2n$ (B) $2^{n+1}$ (C) $2^{n−1}$ (D) $2^{2n}$

Any hints as to how to approach this problem ?

Comment: It's a bit cheating, but for a choice question like this, just plug some (small) values in $n$ and see which results you'll get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2^{2n+1}$ subsets in total. Now note that the function which takes a subset to its complement is a bijection, and that a subset has n or fewer elements if, and only if, its complement has more than n elements.

This implies that the number of subsets with n or fewer elements is equal to the number with more than n.

Therefore, the answer is $\displaystyle \frac{2^{2n+1}}{2}=2^{2n}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Sum the number of subsets with exactly $k$ elements for all $k=0\dots n\,$, and use the binomial theorem, and that the number of subsets of size $x$ equals to the number of size $N-x$ if teh base set is of size $N$.